# Does including parenthesis in ko binding affect order of evaluation? Why?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using KO with some pretty straightforward code, but I'm seeing something strange.

```
<div class="upload-progress" data-bind="visible: isUploading">
  <div class="upload-progress-spinner" data-bind="spinner: isUploading" />
</div>
```

This makes the spinner (second div) appear a little out of position, but if I add parenthesis in that second ko binding as follows:

```
<div class="upload-progress" data-bind="visible: isUploading">
  <div class="upload-progress-spinner" data-bind="spinner: isUploading()" />
</div>
```

... the position is now correct. Why would adding parenthesis in my ko binding have an effect such as this? My guess is that it somehow changes the order of evaluation, but I am not sure exactly why. Anybody have any insight here?

Note: "spinner" is a custom KO binding, but I don't believe its logic is causing this positioning quirk.

EDIT: here is the spinner custom binding, in case it is relevant:

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.spinner = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
  var bindingValue = valueAccessor().show || valueAccessor();
  var defaults = { lines: 8, length: 2, width: 2, radius: 3, speed: 1.3, trail: 60, shadow: false };
  var options = valueAccessor().options || {};
  $.extend(options, defaults);

  if (bindingValue)
    setTimeout(function () { $(element).spin(options); }, 1);
  else
    $(element).spin(false);
}
```

};

Comment: `var foo = bar()` immediately executes the bar function and assigns its return value to foo. `var foo = bar` would assign the value of bar to foo. If bar is a function, then foo becomes essentially a pointer to the function, and later on you can do `foo()` and the bar code would execute.

Comment: `spinner: isUploading` allows knockout to observe the observable and modify the binding when it changes.  `spinner: isUploading()` will evaluate the observable and pass the value to the `spinner` binding when the element is rendered, and changes won't be passed across.  Why that changes what you're seeing depends on what the `spinner` binding is expecting and what it's doing with what it's given, hence a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks for the answer. I've included the code for my spinner binding, which doesn't do anything terribly interesting.

Comment: @FreakinOutMan Do you get any errors in your browser console/does the spinner actually function as expected when running the second version?  It looks like it's expecting an observable to be passed to it (it's calling `valueAccessor()`, so if `isUploading` is a boolean observable (which I assume it is based on it's name and the fact you're using it on `visible`), I would expect passing `isUploading()` to it (which in turn will effectively call `true()` or `false()` inside the binding) to cause some problems

Comment: @JamesThorpe I get no errors and the spinner functions properly with either version. Position is incorrect in the first snippet, but correct with the second snippet. I guess KO is smart enough to figure out that what I give the binding is an observable whether I include the parens or not?

Comment: Please try to update your question with the minimal code sample to reproduce the issue. Without that we have to resort to guessing what's going on. (Preferably create a runnable Stack Snippet exhibiting the behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supsect you are not reading the configured options correctly because you're not properly 'unwrapping' the observable in your binding handler.

So you're really calling the spinner with different options depending on whether you supply the parentheses or not... that's the real issue.

You should do this (Note this is knockout 3 syntax, use ko.unwrapObservable if you're using knockout 2.x)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.spinner = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
        var bindingValue = valueUnwrapped.show || valueUnwrapped;
        var defaults = { lines: 8, length: 2, width: 2, radius: 3, speed: 1.3, trail: 60, shadow: false };
        var options = valueUnwrapped.options || {}; // this is the key line
        $.extend(options, defaults);

       if (bindingValue)
           setTimeout(function () { $(element).spin(options); }, 1);
       else
           $(element).spin(false);
       }
   }
```

From the doc:

> valueAccessor — A JavaScript function that you can call to get the
>   current model property that is involved in this binding. Call this
>   without passing any parameters (i.e., call valueAccessor()) to get the
>   current model property value. To easily accept both observable and
>   plain values, call ko.unwrap on the returned value

Comment: Figures that the assumption I made ("my custom binding is fine") turned out to be the problem. Properly unwrapping the value fixes the issue! Thanks!